# Where to configure the default user group for file/directory creation?

Tags: macos, filesystem, active-directory

I would like to configure the default group for any file or directory which is created by my user. I am not sure where to start. Could somebody point me the right direction? My user lives in Active Directory and by default I get the default AD group. I am wondering if I could override this behavior on my computer.

`[myuser::~]touch test_file`

`[myuser::~]ls -alrth test_file`

`-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  AD\Domain Users     0B Mar 19 10:40 test_file`

Comment: Can you clarify this question? Where is the your user creating the files (locally, SMB share, AFP share, etc.)? Are you doing SSO on a Mac bound to AD? How are POSIX/ACLs provisioned on whatever drive? More info will help you get a good answer to this.

Comment: I am using my Mac with AD. The file is created on the local drive in my home directory. How could I check the ACLs?

Comment: ACLs are typically only used in a server environment. Your paste above shows the POSIX.

Comment: So how can I control the POSIX process? I would like to change so that my files and directories are created with a local group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this. Since network accounts have their groups managed by the network account server, it doesn't look like this can be overridden locally. And since the user is part of the network account server they are technically not part of a local user group.

As a test, I used Advanced Options to modify my network user to group 80 (local admins group). Upon reboot my user belonged to the AD group again.

If you want to change group ownership, you will probably need to use the `chown user:group` functionality in the Terminal on each file or folder you want to modify ownership permissions over.

Another option, of course, is to work off of a local user account and use your network credentials when accessing network resources. You will lose awesome things like single-sign-on though.

Comment: I see. There is no way to change the default group of any new file creation than I guess. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Correct. Other than having the Active Directory administrator change your AD group. But it's not gonna be a local group regardless.